# Preview Collective Articles

Tags: feature-request, collectives, articles, draft

After writing the draft for an article in one of the Collectives, I noticed that there's no way to see how the article looks like before submitting it for review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With markdown disabled in the article editor, you can see how the article will look when it's published.

If you'll be using markdown when composing the article, be sure to start composing with markdown enabled (which is the default setting). Then you can toggle it on and off for a preview whenever you like.

In order to see that icon you might need to scroll to the side in the article body

[image]

Comment: Didn't know it was possible to scroll there to the side and get a markdown toggle... Well spotted, thanks!